# How to stop taskgated on Sierra?

Tags: macos

When I just `sudo pkill` it:

```
sudo pkill taskgated
```

In syslog:

```
Apr 17 12:08:46 genesis com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.taskgated[88619]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by pkill[90814]
```

However it automatically restarts:

```
ps aux | grep taskgated
root             90981   0.0  0.0  2462316   1668   ??  Ss   12:08PM   0:00.01 /usr/libexec/taskgated -s
```

Also note, that using `launchctl` is also not the way to do it:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated*.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated-helper.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

Answer (score 2):

Launchd is keeping the process alive. You need to run

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated*.plist
```

to unload the daemon. To load it again, run:

```
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated*.plist
```

Comment: Not on Sierra. This is a protected process. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that I have SIP disabled sometimes. I guess there's no way to do it without disabling SIP, after all, `taskgated` is designed by for security.

Answer (score 0):

This process cannot be forcefully killed because the another process automatically reopens it. Try killing it non-forcefully.